# access angular $cookies from non-angular code

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I have a `test` module that set cookie `isTesting` to be true

```
app.controller('test_page',
    ['$scope', '$window', 'userService', 'flash', '$cookies',
function($scope, $window, userService, flash, $cookies) {
    helper.initCommonScope($scope, $window, userService, flash)

    $scope.refreshShownHidden = function() {
        $scope.showTurnOffTest = $cookies.get('isTesting')
        $scope.showTurnOnTest = ! $cookies.get('isTesting')
    }

    $scope.turnOnTest = function() {

        $cookies.put('isTesting', true)
        $scope.refreshShownHidden()
        helper.turnOnTest()
    }
    $scope.turnOffTest = function() {
        $cookies.put('isTesting', false)
        $scope.refreshShownHidden()
        helper.turnOffTest()
    }

    $scope.refreshShownHidden()

}])
```

And in helper.js, I have

```
exports.havePermission = function(access, resource, userService, entity) {
    //Note: In debugging, we can grant client helper all access, and test robustness of server
    if (angular.$cookies.isTesting)
        return true
    return permission.havePermission(access, resource, userService.isAuthenticated(), entity, userService.user)
}
```

But $cookies is not available since `helper.js` is not part of any angular module, thus no DI is available. How can I access the `isTesting` value?

I have tried using `window.isTesting` instead but it's not persisted when I refresh the page or go to other pages. So cookie is a better choice

Comment: Pass $cookies, or the cookie itself, as argument? Make helper an angular service, so that you can inject $cookies inside?

Comment: I use helper all over the places. I dont think I can modify all the controllers to pass $cookies. any other ways?

Comment: Also, some initialialization code which is outside a function requires the cookie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Angular's injector to access Angular modules and services outside of your Angular application.

**AngularJS Code**

```
angular.module('app', ['ngCookies']).
  controller('ctrl', ['$cookies', function($cookies) {
    $cookies.put('isTesting', true);
  }]);
```

**Non-Angular Code**

```
helper = {
  getCookies: function() {
    // Create new injector for ngCookies module
    var $injector = angular.injector(['ngCookies']);

    // Inject $cookies to some function and invoke it
    $injector.invoke(['$cookies', function($cookies) {
      alert($cookies.get('isTesting'));
    }]);
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<html ng-app='app'>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.3" data-semver="1.4.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-cookies.js@1.4.3" data-semver="1.4.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="helper.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="ctrl">
    <button onclick="helper.getCookies()">Click Me</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/jur9A6d69ViiJqiFgopD?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

```
var cookies = angular.injector(['ngCookies']).get('$cookies');
```

It creates a new instance of `$cookies` service, so if you're using it across the app, it is better to export it to global.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the AngularJS purpose. You should try to keep all your stuff in your AngularJS code. However you can set any global variable in AngularJS:

```
app.controller('test_page',
    ['$scope', '$window', 'userService', 'flash', '$cookies',
function($scope, $window, userService, flash, $cookies) {
    angular.$cookies = $cookies;
    // or window.$cookies = $cookies;
    helper.initCommonScope($scope, $window, userService, flash)
```

Then you can access $cookies anytime anywhere. It make certain things easier but less safe (any other script can access it too, it can create conflict, etc.)

Comment: is angular under window?

Comment: if i dont assign it to angular, where can I find the cookie?

Comment: Yep, else, you could not write angular.module(...)

Comment: If you do not call the controller every time, call it in .run / .config / .directive / .service / .factory

Comment: i dont like to pollute the globals. Any place to find $scope (it's original place)? or anyway to `wrap document.cookie`?

Comment: just tried, not working. when I refresh the page, isTesting is persisted in $cookies, but angular.$cookies is not defined (since I dont click it again). It's basically the same problem as assigning window.isTesting